# R Creating new columns using for loop that generate vectors contains name of variables

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, statistics

I have data and i have vectors that contain name of variables
Using this vectors i want to create new columns that contain the sum of variables  present vector
the vectors are generated by for loop so i don't know the number of vectors neither the variables that are present in each vector i.e in every time i generate vec that contain diffrent variables names

for example : let's assume that my loop will generate these three vectors : Vec when i=1 Vec when i=2 and Vec when i=3

```
Vec >
Vec >
Vec >
"A","B","C"
"B","D"
"D","E"
```

Here's the data
>data

```
Name      A    B    C    D    E
r1        1    5    12  21    15
r2        2    4     7  10     9
r3        5   15     6   9     6
r4        7    8     0   7    18
```

Here's the first result i should obtain ( start with the first vector)

```
    Name      A    B    C     ABC      D      E          
     r1       1    5   12     18      21     15         
     r2       2    4    7     13      10      9        
     r3       5   15    6     26       9      6         
     r4       7    8    0     15       7     18
```

And here's the final result

```
Name      A    B    C     ABC        D       BD      E          DE
 r1       1    5   12     18         21      26      15         36 
 r2       2    4    7     13         10      14       9         19
 r3       5   15    6     26          9      24       6         15
 r4       7    8    0     15          7      15      18         25
```

i.e V1 contain name of variables "A" , "B" , "C" and ABC contains the sum of variables A, B and C
ans the same for BD( sum of B and D ), and DE (sum of D and E)

Note also that i want the name of my new columns to be the names of columns present in the vectors

Please tell me if you need more informations and more explications or details

Comment: Its is better to include a toy set that can be copy pasted, by using `dput()`. In your case this will result in `structure(list(Name = c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4"), A = c(1, 2, 
5, 7), B = c(5, 4, 15, 8), C = c(12, 7, 6, 0), D = c(21, 10, 
9, 7), E = c(15, 9, 6, 18)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L))`. This makes it a bit easier on people trying to find a solution.

Comment: Question: is the place of insertion important? I.e should "ABC" always be placed after C and before D?

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `purrr::reduce`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Name = c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4"),
                 A = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 7L),
                 B = c(5L, 4L, 15L, 8L),
                 C = c(12L, 7L, 6L, 0L),
                 D = c(21L, 10L, 9L, 7L),
                 E = c(15L, 9L, 6L, 18L)
      )
vts <- list(c("A","B","C"),c("B","D"),c("D","E"))

reduce(vts, function(x,y)
  bind_cols(x, !!paste0(y,collapse = "") := rowSums(x[,y])), .init=df) 

#>   Name A  B  C  D  E ABC BD DE
#> 1   r1 1  5 12 21 15  18 26 36
#> 2   r2 2  4  7 10  9  13 14 19
#> 3   r3 5 15  6  9  6  26 24 15
#> 4   r4 7  8  0  7 18  15 15 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

v <- list(c("A","B","C"),c("B","D"),c("D","E"))

express <- setNames(v, map(v, str_flatten)) %>% 
  imap(~ parse_expr(sprintf("rowSums(across(c(%s)))", paste(.x, collapse = ","))))

df %>% 
  mutate(!!! express)
```

**Output**

```
  Name A  B  C  D  E ABC BD DE
1   r1 1  5 12 21 15  18 26 36
2   r2 2  4  7 10  9  13 14 19
3   r3 5 15  6  9  6  26 24 15
4   r4 7  8  0  7 18  15 15 25
```